# Trouble with a crontab script modification failing

Tags: scripts, cron, tar

I have a crontab that calls a script syslogtar.sh in /usr/bin.  It is in my path and has been running fine for over a year.  The script goes into each firewall log directory runs a find command pipes the output to tar to tar the files and remove the tarred gz files.  We added a few new firewalls so I added new lines to handle tarring logs on those but it is not working.  I have tried reloading the crond and rebooting the serevr thinking that the script needed to be updated in the cron "memory" but still no luck.  When i check the individual lines I take one that has worked and run it and it finds the files and tars them just like this:

```
root@stgapsclsplc01:/usr/bin#  find /syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/*.gz -mtime +1 | xargs  tar --remove-files -cvPf /syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar

/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546838222.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546841822.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546845421.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546849022.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546852622.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546856222.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546859822.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546863421.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546867021.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546870621.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546874222.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546877821.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546881421.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546885021.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546888621.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546892221.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546895821.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546899421.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546903021.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546906621.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546910221.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.78/10.10.10.78.log-20190107-1546913821.gz
```

i have a new firewall so I added:

```
find /syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/*.gz -mtime +1 | xargs  tar --remove-files -cvPf /syslog/sog-firewalls/psc/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar
```

When I try the find portion:

```
find /syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/*.gz -mtime +1
```

It returns a number of files

```
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190102-1546485422.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190102-1546489023.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190103-1546492621.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190103-1546496223.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190103-1546499822.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190103-1546503422.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190103-1546507021.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190103-1546510623.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190103-1546514224.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190103-1546517821.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190103-1546521421.gz
/syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91.log-20190103-1546525021.gz
..........Abreiviated
```

However when I run the entire command I get:

```
root@stgapsclsplc01:/usr/bin# find /syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/*.gz -mtime +1 | xargs  tar --remove-files -cvPf /syslog/sog-firewalls/psc/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar
tar: /syslog/sog-firewalls/psc/10.10.10.91/10.10.10.91_2019-01-09.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have checked permission and looked over syntax so many times But I am not finding anything amiss.  The command is exactly the same as the working one except is is working in a different directory and filenames.  I have verified the path multiple times.  Does anyone know why one works and the new one will not?

Comment: I don't know if it's significant, but `find` should take a path (or list of paths) rather than a list of files - you can limit its results to `.gz` files by specifying a `-name` pattern e.g. `find /syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/ -name '*.gz'` in place of `find /syslog/firewalls/isp/10.10.10.91/*.gz`

Comment: Thanks, I can add that, but I dont think that is the cause of the issue I am seeing since most of the lines work fine and it is the tar portion of the command that is erroring out not the find portion.